# "Importing" phonegap project into new phonegap app

Tags: cordova

So I have a software provider that gave me the source code of the app. But he removed all the phonegap files, so I ended up with the following file structure:

[image: file structure]

I tried importing from phonegap, which just does not work.
How could I create a new project but reuse that source code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project (Using command line or anything you prefer)

Goto your old project and copy config.xml, plugins folder and www folder.

Paste them into your new project.

Try compiling in your new project.

Comment: My project has no config.xml :/

Comment: Could be in somewhere in the folders. Otherwise, it'll be difficult to analyze what plugins are used for the project as well as setting.